# Lightbox CSS/JS gallery integration to WordPress image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

I am a beginner with WordPress.
I have a HTML/BOOTSTARP "One page" template which has a gallery built with Lightbox CSS/JS.

Refer the template link [here](https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524991-oxygen-free-bootstrap-one-page-theme).

I have integrated this theme to WordPress and everything works fine.

Now, I would like to upload pictures to this existing gallery using WordPress.
A post creation is giving me options to upload this as a new post.

I have 8 portfolios and would like to add several pictures to specific portfolios from WordPress so that it could be automatically uploaded.

Please be reminded that this is a One page website.

```html
<section id="portfolio">
  <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
          <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
         
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="folio-item wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="folio-image">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="overlay-content">
                <div class="overlay-text">
                  <div class="folio-info">
                    <h3>gallery</h3>
                    <p></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="folio-overview">
                    <span class="folio-link"><a class="folio-read-more" href="#" data-single_url="portfolio-single.php" ><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></span>
                    <span class="folio-expand"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/portfolio-details.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="folio-item wow fadeInLeftBig" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">
            <div class="folio-image">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="overlay-content">
                <div class="overlay-text">
                  <div class="folio-info">
                   <!-- <h3>Time Hours</h3>
                    <p>Design, Photography</p>-->
                  </div>
                  <div class="folio-overview">
                    <span class="folio-link"><a class="folio-read-more" href="#" data-single_url="portfolio-single.php" ><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></span>
                    <span class="folio-expand"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/portfolio-details.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="folio-item wow fadeInRightBig" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="500ms">
            <div class="folio-image">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="overlay-content">
                <div class="overlay-text">
                  <div class="folio-info">
                    <!--<h3>Time Hours</h3>
```

Code for the portfolio

Kindly help me with your suggestions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/2.jpg" alt="">

<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img//portfolio/portfolio-details.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
```

has double slash "//" which leads to not finding the actual file.

Besides that, have you checked that Lightbox CSS and JavaScript file are loaded properly? See the console if there is any error.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur response. I think you have not  got my query right. I am a beginner, and have no idea on how to make this code to make upload images from wordpress dashboard. Should I have to create a post? or a widget? or add some plugin...I couldnt find answer for this query anywhere. May be this is simple..But I couldnt get the answer. Kindly help me with it